# Start Eclipse with Equinox inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I'm trying to launch Eclipse inside another Eclipse programmatically and set the plugins to load with the `osgi.bundles=...`-parameter in config.ini file.

I tried to start the second eclipse instance with the EclipseStarter class but I'm getting the following exception:

```
EclipseStarter.setInitialProperties(props);
BundleContext context = EclipseStarter.startup(new String[] {}, null);
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform already running

I also tried it with starting a new Equinox instance:

```
FrameworkFactory factory = new EquinoxFactory();
Framework newFramework = factory.newFramework(props);
newFramework.start();
```

But then there will be nothing started. 
Any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't run another Eclipse in the same JVM, you must create a new JVM and also specify a different workspace.

Comment: The workspace for the second instance is specified in the props via `-data/osgi.instance.area`. So the only way for starting the second instance is to start it with `java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_xxx.jar`?

Comment: Either that or all the `ILaunchConfiguration` support - which is very flexible but complex.